# Compiling C++ with -m32 With Cygwin G++ Windows 64bit Error

Tags: mingw, mingw32

I am trying to compile my c++ program with -m32 using cygwin g++ but I get an error when I try to do so.

From what I read about the problem, I need to download a package from cygwin package manager that will allow `-m32` to work but I am not sure which package it is. Another post I read said I had to install `gcc-multilib` and `g++-multilib` from the package manager but those packages are not in the selection of packages available.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when     searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when     searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when     searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when     searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a     when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a     when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a     when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when     searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when     searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when     searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when     searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when     searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:     cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the `{gcc|g++}-mulitlib` packages are not provided by the cygwin
package manager.

To build 32-bit C++ targets, install package `mingw64-i686-gcc-g++`, which
is the mingw64 cross compiler for 32-bit targets. Then build with the
compiler `/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++`. There is no need for the `-m32`
option.

Comment: `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` works for me in 64bit cygwin

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to use `-static` because libraries couldn't because found!